# Passing GET value to WP widget

Tags: php, wordpress

A im creating some custom widget in Word Press, but what i need is that i can pass GET value inside my widget, i have tried many ways but no luck, here is my widget code in WP for now

```
class Trucks extends WP_Widget{

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct(false, $name = __('Truck API'));
    }

    function form(){

    }

    function update(){

    }

    function widget($args, $instance){
        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        if(isset($_GET['a'])) {
            $test = $_GET['a'];
            echo $test;
        } 
        else {
            $test = 'Nothing';
        }

    }

}

add_action('widgets_init', function(){ 
    register_widget('Trucks');
});


?>
```

It diplay for now nothing, it is much more complex class, but this is made simple to understand what i need :)

Comment: get is a supervariable so its always available. Check the uri is there a value `?a=something`?

Comment: Can you please write answer to see

Comment: I appreciate the code has been simplified for the purpose of the question however that makes it difficult to determine whether there's an issue with the actual code or the way it has been simplified. Providing your widget has been registered correctly, added to the page, confirmed to generate output and you've set 'a' in the URL I can't see why you'd have any trouble.